# How to use IronPython in SharpDevelop C# with .Net framework version 4.0

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I want to use IronPython package in my project, but when i want to install it.

it shows:"Could not instal package IronPython 2.7.8.1. you are trying to install this package into a project that targets'NetFramework,versiont=4.0' but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. for more information contact the package author"

Please help me~

Comment: Just putting it out there, what do you think it means?

Comment: also have a look at this page, https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPython and tell me what you think the dependencies are telling you?

Comment: Also if you go into your project properties -> application and look at the target framework, what do you think thats saying ? i think if you think this through, it might click and it will all become clear